# problem with converting the output from linq query to string

Tags: asp.net, linq

I'm sorry to ask this basic question,

```
var filePath = (from Component comp1 in componentContainer where comp1.ComponentName == fileName select comp1.FilePath);
```

I want to convert the output to string.

I tried these things:

```
string filePath = (from Component comp1 in componentContainer where comp1.ComponentName == fileName select comp1.FilePath).ToString();
```

and

```
 var filePath = (from Component comp1 in componentContainer where comp1.ComponentName == fileName select comp1.FilePath);
        string filePathInString = filePath.ToString();
```

both times i'm getting error:

```
Linq.Internals.UnoptimizedQuery<string>
```

Please help me out

How should i solve this problem ?

PS: If some one thinks this question is stupid or for some reason does not like it. U may delete this question after getting answered instead of flagging or down voting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the query to

```
string filePath = (from Component comp1 in componentContainer where comp1.ComponentName == fileName select comp1.FilePath).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Comment: If comp1.FilePath is a string you shouldn't need to call the ToString() method.

Comment: u r my saviour!! Thanks a lot!! It worked !! But why won't it work if i don't add FirstOrDefault() ?? Can you please explain it for me ??

Comment: @user653622 The result of your query is an `IEnumerable<string>`. `FirstOrDefault()` returns the first item in the results (or null if the results are empty).

Answer (score 1):

```
string filePath=componentContainer.Single(x=>x.ComponentName==fileName).FilePath;
```